# How can I prevent a buyer from seeing my (company's) name on the PayPal receipt?

Tags: paypal

I initiated a test donation to my IndieGoGo campaign, and noticed, that supporter see my full name (*Premier* account) or my company name (*Bussiness* account) on payment summary screen (and probably in the payment confirmation e-mail):

[image]

However, when I'm trying to donate some program, I don't see neither company name, nor owner name, just the program name:

[image]

Can I achieve the same for IndieGoGo? How can I run a campaign and let people pay without revealing my name (owner) or my company name on payment summary screen (above example) or in the payment confirmation e-mail?

I can't find proper settings / options in PayPal's configuration and repeated requests to PayPal Supports ends up with "autogenerated" answers (copy-paste from their FAQ), that doesn't bring me to the solution even a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide company name on PayPal's receipt, when your PayPal account is set as `Business`. Customer sending money to such e-mail (and this is how it goes at Indiegogo) will *always* see:

- company name,
- customers support phone number,
- company e-mail address (default one for particular account).

There is no way to change this.

To achieve situation presented on second screenshot, one must define its own [Payment Buttons](https://www.paypal.com/pl/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_wp-standard-overview) in `Merchant Services` section at PayPal and use only them. This method of paying however is not supported at Indiegogo, where money from supporters goes to PayPal account via e-mail.

So this is either way:

- direct payment to your company's e-mail address, were key details are visible,
- paying via click on special button on your own website, where users sees only product details.

Can't have both in the same time.